# How to use substitute command in unix(vi or sed) to achieve the following results

Tags: unix

How to use substitute command in UNIX(vi or sed) to achieve the following result. My data is like this for example `char(10) null, char(20) null, char(11) not null`. I want to modify a line which has `char()` and `null` and not with `char()` and `not null`. The modified line should be like `varchar(10) null`. 
 Whole idea is char to be replaced by var char with the bytes remaining unchanged and with only null parameter.

Thank you

Comment: Depending on how well formated your data is already,

1. You could activate vim interactive search and replace and decide manually
     - :%s/char/varchar/gc

2. Try to regex match occurrences

Comment: Note the 'c' flag at the end of the command. This will make vi/m prompt before each replacement. See ':help substitute' for more info. This will take a while though because it is manual. EDIT: it seems you deleted your comment but I will leave this up to clarify regardless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test the following command without the `-i` option for making it perfect.
The regex between `\(` and `\)` is remembered and returned in `\1`.

```
sed -i 's/char(\([0-9]*\)) not null/varchar(\1) not null/' file
```

Comment: superb , much thanks.
i used sed 's/\(char.....null\)/var\1/g' and increased one dot (".")  every time for increase in each byte length . but your solution is one time execution . thanks again .

Answer (score 0):

sed -i "s/char/varchar/" filename.txt

Comment: let me repharse my question there are 2 scenarios or two types of lines .
1) abc char( 10) null.
2) xyz char(10) not null.


i need to only change the line which has null as parameter (line 1) , if i follow your solution it will change all the lines with string 'char' whereas i need to consider line with both 'char' and 'null' also the byte size in the bracket will vary so i cannot use 'char(10)' as some will have char(11), char(5) etc.
hope my question is clear now